# It is unable to restart postgresql in wsl(ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on Windows. I can not start postgresql status down to online. At the time I just installed postgres 11, the status was online at port 5433 and it seemed working well. Then it went down and never goes online again.

The postgresql status is now

```
11/main (port 5433): down
```

and when I try to restart by `sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main restart`, `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`, then the error code goes like below.

```
Restarting PostgreSQL 11 database server
Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl 
start -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11- 
main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf"  
exited with status 1:
2019-04-02 19:36:27.783 DST [3195] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address 
"127.0.0.1", port 5433
2019-04-02 19:36:27.798 DST [3195] LOG:  listening on Unix socket 
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"
2019-04-02 19:36:27.852 DST [3196] LOG:  database system was interrupted; 
last known up at 2019-04-02 18:39:14 DST
2019-04-02 19:36:27.853 DST [3196] PANIC:  could not flush dirty data: 
Function not implemented
2019-04-02 19:36:27.853 DST [3195] LOG:  startup process (PID 3196) was 
terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2019-04-02 19:36:27.853 DST [3195] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup 
process failure
2019-04-02 19:36:27.860 DST [3195] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I thought the problem was related to port settings, so I looked up some files.
At /etc/services, postgresql is set as 5432

```
postgresql      5432/tcp        postgres        # PostgreSQL Database
postgresql      5432/udp        postgres
```

and at /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf, the port is set as 5433

```
port = 5433
```

I don't know why the port number is set different with each other. Since there is nothing running on both port 5432, 5433, I really don't know why the postgresql cannot go on online status.
Let me know if there is more informations to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem.

And I just turn the `fsync` option to `off`(this option is in the postgresql.conf file), then everything turns okay. Becareful, this workaround is not suitable for production environment.

Check this for detail:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121820/postgresql-not-starting